# Violin plot not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am trying to generate a violin plot for a given dataset. The data varies from 0 to 100. But the violin plot goes over 100 and goes below 0.

How can I limit it between 0 to 100?

**Code Used:**

```
library(ggplot2)

input_data <- read.csv("C:/Temp/Recall.csv")
input_data
precision_in_percentage <- input_data$ResultValue



# Basic violin plot
p <- ggplot(input_data, aes(x='TRAssociation', y=precision_in_percentage)) +
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE, fill='#A4A4A4', color="darkred")+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.05) + theme_minimal()

p
```

**Violin Plot:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the documentation for `geom_violin()`, it looks like you should remove the `trim=False` specification. By default, ggplot2 sets `trim = True`.

From ggplot2 [docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html):

> trim: If TRUE (default), trim the tails of the violins to the range
>   of the data. If 
>       FALSE, don't trim the tails.

Note that if you like the shape of the geom_violin() and just want to restrict the y-axis boundaries, you can do that by adding `+ ylim(0, 100)` to your plotting function calls.

Also, note that there is a boxplot tool that plays better with violin plots available via the `stat_summary()` function. Try removing your call to `geom_boxplot()` and instead using this (you may want to play with the `shape` and `size` parameters:

`+ stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", fill="white", shape=21, size=2.5)`

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html) for that function can be found here. It looks like trim=TRUE might be used for this.

> If TRUE (default), trim the tails of the violins to the range of the
>   data. If FALSE, don't trim the tails.

Hope this helps!